# Salesforce Code Coverage Failure: Cannot deploy Apex Trigger in Production despite 100% code coverage in Sandbox

Tags: triggers, salesforce, code-coverage, apex

I have a code coverage of 100% for my trigger in Sandbox but when uploading my packages to production I have an error

*Code Coverage Failure
Your code coverage is 74%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.*

I really don't understand why the error, despite my code being covered 100% in Sandbox
[image]

I do not have any other test class for my code

[image]

What am I missing?
Thanks

here my Trigger

```
trigger CaseConcernAircallDateTrigger on Task (after insert) {
   
    List<Case>  cList = new List<Case>();
    for(Task t: Trigger.New) {
        if(t.WhatId!=Null && t.whatId.getsObjectType() == Case.sObjectType){
            Case c = new Case();
            c.Id = t.whatId;
            c.Last_Aircall_Logged__c = t.CreatedDate;
            cList.add(c);
          
        }
     
    }
   
    if(cList.size() > 0) update cList;
}
```

here my Test class

```
@isTest
  public class CaseConcernAircallDateTriggerTest {
      @isTest static void testAircallDateUpdate() {
        
        Contact con = new Contact (FirstName = 'First Name',LastName = 'Test');
        insert con;
        
        Case c = new Case(Status = 'New',ContactId = con.Id,Phone_Number__c = '123456789');
        insert c;
        
        Task t = new Task(Subject = 'Test', WhatId = c.Id);
        insert t;
       
        c.Id = t.WhatId;
        c.Last_Aircall_Logged__c = t.CreatedDate;
        update c;
       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's OK, I found the solution.
I was updating the list directly which was causing the code coverage failure.

I just changed
if(cList.size() > 0) update cList; to

if(cList.size() > 0) upsert cList;